# Determining max database and table size supported and present size

Tags: mysql, mysql-5

One of my MySQL databases has been running on a single PC from the last four years.

Here is my setup:

- MySQL 5.5.14
- Windows XP on NTFS partition
- All of my tables are using InnoDB engine

Here are two things I want to determine:

- the maximum database and table size supported by this version and engine on the platform I mentioned above
- the current database size and table sizes of all the tables in a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some nice queries I have used for years:

This reports the amount of data and indexes for each storage engine:

```
SELECT IFNULL(B.engine,'Total') "Storage Engine", CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.DSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Data Size", CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.ISize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Index Size", CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.TSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Table Size" FROM (SELECT engine,SUM(data_length) DSize,SUM(index_length) ISize,SUM(data_length+index_length) TSize FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema') AND engine IS NOT NULL GROUP BY engine WITH ROLLUP) B,
(SELECT 3 pw) A ORDER BY TSize;
```

This reports the amount of data and indexes for each database:

```
SELECT DBName,CONCAT(LPAD(FORMAT(SDSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Data Size",CONCAT(LPAD(FORMAT(SXSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Index Size",CONCAT(LPAD(FORMAT(STSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Total Size" FROM (SELECT IFNULL(DB,'All Databases') DBName,SUM(DSize) SDSize,SUM(XSize) SXSize,SUM(TSize) STSize FROM (SELECT table_schema DB,data_length DSize,index_length XSize,data_length+index_length TSize FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema')) AAA GROUP BY DB WITH ROLLUP) AA,
(SELECT 3 pw) BB ORDER BY (SDSize+SXSize);
```

This reports the amount of data and indexes for each database  by storage engine:

```
SELECT Statistic,DataSize "Data Size",IndexSize "Index Size",TableSize "Table Size" FROM (SELECT IF(ISNULL(table_schema)=1,10,0) schema_score,IF(ISNULL(engine)=1,10,0) engine_score,IF(ISNULL(table_schema)=1,'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',table_schema) schemaname,IF(ISNULL(B.table_schema)+ISNULL(B.engine)=2,"Storage for All Databases",IF(ISNULL(B.table_schema)+ISNULL(B.engine)=1,CONCAT("Storage for ",B.table_schema),CONCAT(B.engine," Tables for ",B.table_schema))) Statistic,CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.DSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') DataSize,CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.ISize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') IndexSize,CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.TSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') TableSize FROM (SELECT table_schema,engine,SUM(data_length) DSize,SUM(index_length) ISize,SUM(data_length+index_length) TSize FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema') AND engine IS NOT NULL GROUP BY table_schema,engine WITH ROLLUP) B,
(SELECT 3 pw) A) AA ORDER BY schemaname,schema_score,engine_score;
```

Please notice at the end of each query there is an inline query `(SELECT 3 pw)`. The pw is simply an exponent used as a power of 1024. Here is how to use this:

- `(SELECT 0 pw)` reports in bytes
- `(SELECT 1 pw)` reports in kilobytes
- `(SELECT 2 pw)` reports in megabytes
- `(SELECT 3 pw)` reports in gigabytes
- `(SELECT 4 pw)` reports in terabytes
- `(SELECT 5 pw)` reports in petabytes (If you got this much data, write me or at least post the display in DBA.SE. I'm sure we'd all love to see that)

Give it a Try !!!

As for table limits, here are those limits for [**MyISAM**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) and [**InnoDB**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-restrictions.html).

Comment: thanks for the queries. I tried them and they are working fine. I am confused on the maximum table size supported. The link you provided says maximum tablespace size for InnoDB is 64TB?

Comment: @RPK - That is correct. However, please remember that if you use innodb_file_per_table, then the max table size is 64TB.

Comment: This means each InnoDB table max size is 64 TB and that itself determines the max. database size?

Comment: @RPK - If innodb_file_per_table is disabled, then that limits the ibdata1 file 64TB since ibdata1 is a shared tablespace file. If innodb_file_per_table is enabled, each table's size limit is 64TB.