# MySQL information_schema doesn't update

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, percona-server

I have a database, say `abc`, in mysql server. It has only one table named `test`. `test` uses innodb engine and I've set `innodb_file_per_table` to true.

After I run the query `delete from abc.test`, I want to calculate the database size of `abc`. Here is the query I use:

```
SELECT
    table_schema "name",
    sum( IF(engine = "MyISAM", data_length + index_length -  data_free,
    data_length + index_length)) "size"
FROM information_schema.TABLES
where table_schema like "abc";
```

The strange thing is that I find the database size doesn't decrease at all, however the data in "test" is gone.

I've done this kind of test many times, this strange behavior happens sometimes.

I'm using `percona mysql server 5.5.29-rel29.4.`

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

**Update:**

Actually, I use another thread to check the database size periodically.

Comment: Questions: 1) When you ran `delete from abc.testl`, did `/var/lib/mysql/abc/test1.ibd` shrink or stay the same size? 2) Did `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1` grow ? 3) Did your information_schema query show that the used space decreased or stay the same number ?

Comment: 1) the same size 2) no 3) stay the same

Answer (score 3):

You need to rebuild the table in order to shrink the ibd file. This command will do it:

```
optimize table abc.test;
```

Comment: I know the ibd file won't shrink. I'm trying to get the database size by querying against `information_schema`. The query shows that **sometimes** the database size decreases, **sometimes** not.

Comment: Those values in information_schema are just estimates. The actual size of the table is the size of the ibd file.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you why `/var/lib/mysql/abc/test1.ibd` did not shrink.

The query `delete from abc.testl;` is a `DML` transaction. You simply deleted all the row data. If you want to reclaim the physical space of the `.ibd` file, you need to use `DDL` instead of `DML`. I have answered a question of this nature back on `Jan 17, 2012` : [Problem with InnoDB "per table" file sizes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10779/problem-with-innodb-per-table-file-sizes/10812#10812).

Try the following `DDL` statement:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE abc.testl;
```

If the table has no foreign keys, you can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE abc.test2 LIKE abc.test1;
DROP TABLE abc.test1;
ALTER TABLE abc.test2 RENAME abc.test1;
```

Here is what you can do right after a full delete of all rows:

```
DELETE FROM abc.testl;
ALTER TABLE abc.test1 ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

With regard to checking space, please see my posts with queries that can give you sizes grouped by storage engines and rolled up in summary:

- `Sep 13, 2011` : [Determining max database and table size supported and present size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5707/determining-max-database-and-table-size-supported-and-present-size/5708#5708)
- `Dec 01, 2011` : [MySQL Workbench Database Sizes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8661/mysql-workbench-database-sizes/8662#8662)
- `Jan 11, 2013` : [Translating backup size to database size](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31801/translating-backup-size-to-database-size/31804#31804)

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 1):

For addtion, when you delete some rows in table. Table will be fragmented. Remove the fragment will make your table is shinked. Optimize table like Ike Walker said will help.

Optimization table makes downtime for mysqld.